# Скрипт для вывода чек суммы sha256 каждого файла в каталоге windows

Tags: python

Нужен скрипт или пример кода чтобы выдавать на выводе построчно чек сумму каждого файла например в каталоге windows

Например
сканируем файлы
берем первый попавшийся файл
проверяем чек сумму sha256
выводим результат
4626ab92bdfab66e8fe43efdcee3e0b9c330132d37c7ae987bb031d8a0dcebe3

берем следующий файл
и так до конца пока всё не проверим

Есть примеры реализации или как это сделать можно? Благодарю всех кто откликнется)

Comment: А в чём смысл этого действия?

Comment: выходные данные используются для сравнения с оригинальными чек суммами, нужно реализовать только первую часть кода. у Вас есть примеры?

Comment: Непонятно зачем это делать на питоне. Программ для подсчёта и проверки чексумм в природе вполне достаточно.

Comment: Но даже если уж вам хочется написать самому, то непонятно в чём проблема. Где ваши попытки сделать хоть что-то?

Comment: Проект на python, это не только подсчет чек суммы,  выходные данные используются в качестве входных данных для другой части кода - (Это будет служить зерном)